# Exclude specific object type from the global environment

Tags: r, dataframe

I have many different objects loaded in my global environment. How can I exclude only the data frames and keep the other objects? Example:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(rnorm(10))
DF2 <- data.frame(rnorm(10))
DF3 <- data.frame(rnorm(10))

list1 <- list("a", "b", "c")
list2 <- list("a", "b", "c")
tf <- tempfile()
td <- tempdir()
```

The solution I had in mind looked something like this (of course it didn't work)

```
remove(pattern="*.Rdata")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a function I use for tasks like this. `rmSome()` does just that, removes only **some** of the objects from an environment.  It does this by applying the function given in its first argument (i.e. an `is*` function like `is.data.frame()` for data frames, `is.list()` for lists, etc.) to the list of objects in the given environment and filtering out the results.

```
rmSome <- function(FUN, env = globalenv(), negate = FALSE) {
    fun <- match.fun(FUN)
    if(negate) fun <- Negate(fun)
    objget <- mget(ls(envir = env), envir = env)
    rmnames <- names(Filter(fun, objget))
    rm(list = rmnames, envir = env)
}
```

For example, you can remove all data frames from the global environment with

```
rmSome(is.data.frame)
```

So for your given example, you can remove the all the data frames like this:

```
## -- rm(list=ls()) here --
## Define rmSome() here 
DF1 <- data.frame(rnorm(10))
DF2 <- data.frame(rnorm(10))
DF3 <- data.frame(rnorm(10))
list1 <- list("a", "b", "c")
list2 <- list("a", "b", "c")
tf <- tempfile()
td <- tempdir()

## remove all data frames
rmSome(is.data.frame)
ls()
# [1] "list1"  "list2"  "rmSome" "td"     "tf"
```

On the other hand, if you wanted to keep all the data frames and remove everything else, you would negate the removal of data frames like this:

```
rmSome(is.data.frame, negate = TRUE)
```

So far I haven't found any issues with using the other functions like `is.numeric()`, `is.environment()`, etc. for removing numerics, environments, etc. But the function is not currently set up to handle more than one object type at a time.

**Update 1/28/2015:** `eapply()` can also be used for applying a function to an environment. Here's a second function you could use if you don't like `mget()`.  It can be used just the same as the calls above and is probably the better way to go.

```
rmSome2 <- function(FUN, env = globalenv(), negate = FALSE)  {
    fun <- match.fun(FUN)
    if(negate) fun <- Negate(fun)
    ue <- unlist(eapply(env, fun))
    rm(list = names(ue)[ue], envir = env)
}
```