# how to remove all files from workspace except those you want to keep?

Tags: r

I know when I want to remove all files, I simply perform

```
rm(list=ls(gse))
```

if I want to remove one file for example named "data" I can do

```
rm(data)
```

what if I have so many files and I want to remove everything but only keep one or two or few that I want ?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142088/how-to-exclude-only-the-data-frames-from-the-global-environment-in-r/28142128#28142128) might also be useful

Comment: @RichardScriven I wonder if this a dupe, what you think?

Comment: to keep only x and y: `rm(list = setdiff(ls(), c('x','y')))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg - Maybe, but not of the one I linked because this doesn't specify data types to be removed

Answer (score 6):

For example

```
rm(list = ls()[!ls() %in% c("abc", "def")])
```

should remove everything but `abc` and `def`.

Answer (score 0):

You could, as an alternative to lukeA's nice answer, write the few files of interest to a `savethese.Rdata` file, then `rm(list=ls(gse))` followed by re-loading the `savethese.Rdata` file.
Klugey, but with the advantage of backing up the items you want.