# Remove all objects of a given type in R

Tags: r

How can I use `rm` to remove all objects *of a certain type* in `R`?

I currently have a bunch of functions defined that I'd like to expunge.

I know `ls` has a `pattern` option, but this would only help if I was naming all the functions in a pattern (I'm not).

Comment: Might be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142088/exclude-or-keep-only-data-frames-from-the-global-environment-in-r

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A variation on @Jilber's answer:

```
rm(list=names(Filter(is.function, mget(ls(all=T)))))
```

Comment: Can you think of a way for this be adjusted to accommodate more complicated type requests? e.g. function or numeric, not data.frame, etc?

Comment: `function(x) is.function(x) || is.numeric(x)`?

Comment: And then `is.data.frame(x)&!is.data.table(x)`--got it!

Comment: I think this is the cleanest option in `base`

Answer (score 4):

My solution is basically to use `mget` to get the class of everything in `ls()`, then subset `ls()` according to when `class=="function"`:

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)[sapply(mget(ls(all=TRUE)), class) == "function"])
```

@Jilber suggests a cleaner alternative:

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)[sapply(mget(ls(all=TRUE)), is.function)])
```

These basic approaches can be expanded to accommodate more complex "genocide" (class-specific purging):

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)[sapply(mget(ls(all=TRUE)), class) %in% 
    c("function", "numeric")])
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)[sapply(mget(ls(all=TRUE)),
                            function(x) is.function(x) | is.numeric(x))])
```

@Jilber's approach also has the advantage that it will catch multi-class objects (most notably, `data.table`s.

Suppose we wanted to remove all `data.frame`s that are not (also) `data.table`s:

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)[sapply(mget(ls(all=TRUE)),
                            function(x) is.data.frame(x) & !is.data.table(x))])
```

Comment: You can also use `is.function` as in `rm(list=ls()[sapply(mget(ls()), is.function)])`.

Comment: That's perfect for the specific question of removing `function`s, I've edited it in. My solution is slightly more flexible--for example, if I wanted to find `function`s _and_ `data.frame`s--though yours could be bent to this end as well.

Comment: @Jilber your approach also raises the point that mine will struggle to differentiate `data.table` and `data.frame` (and any other object type that has `length(class(x))>1`

Answer (score 3):

You may try `ls.str` where you can list objects of a certain `mode` (e.g. `integer`, `list` (data frame) or `function`), or `lsf.str` (returns functions only):

```
# some objects to 'look for'
int1 <- 1
char1 <- "a"
list1 <- data.frame(x1, x2)
fun1 <- function() x1 + x2

# ls()
# ls.str()
ls.str(mode = "function")
funs <- as.character(ls.str(mode = "function"))

lsf.str()
funs <- as.character(lsf.str())

# rm(funs)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an `ls.str()` function that accepts a mode argument. You can get all the functions in the global environment with:

```
ls.str( mode="function")  # or in a different environment if properly created
```

The `exists` function tests whether it can be found and can be limited to particular mode. This is a potentially destructive effect on a running session

```
rm( list = ls()[ sapply( ls(), exists, mode="function")] )
# test for errors and effectiveness
any( sapply( ls(), exists, mode="function"))
# [1] FALSE
```

If you were trying to remove only functions with particular patterns to their names you might select among the character vectors returned by `ls()` with `grepl`.

Comment: Can you think of a way for this be adjusted to accommodate more complicated type requests? e.g. `function` _or_ `numeric`, _not_ `data.frame`, etc?

Comment: Just make the function that tests for mode capable of handling other modes. The mode of a data.frame would be "list". It would require as many calls to exists as you have options in mind.

Answer (score 2):

If you have [Dirk's `lsos` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session) (also available in the `stackoverflow` package), then you could do this:

```
rm(list=rownames(subset(lsos(), Type == "POSIXct")))
```

This might be useful if the class doesn't have a builtin predicate for type checking (such as `is.function`)

Comment: Thanks, that this is more general is great! I am always averse to installing packages, though; anyway, a more specialized version of this would do just fine.