# How do I remove everything from the environment in one go whilst preserving functions?

Tags: r

I often like to clear all variables using `rm(list = ls())` so that I can run a script from scratch; however, this command removes all objects, regardless of type.

I want to preserve all variables listed under 'Functions' in RStudio whilst removing everything else.

I ask because I have two functions in my environment which I would like to preserve, but I also don't want to have to manually type out `rm(var1, var2, df1, df2, ...)` each time I want to remove all variables whilst preserving the 'Functions'.

How can this be done?

Comment: Maybe could this help you to classify your environment objects so you can create a specific list to remove `sapply(ls(), function(x) typeof(get(x)))`

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clearer (current security settings won't allow me to upload an image/screenshot).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767667/remove-all-objects-of-a-given-type-in-r may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `RStudio`, the `Data` items seems to be referring to `data.frame/tibble/data.table` objects.  If that is the case, get the object names that `data.frame` and `rm` them

```
rm(list = ls()[sapply(ls(), \(x) inherits(get(x), 
          what = c("data.frame", "list")))])
```

---

Or may use `eapply`

```
rm(list = names(which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv, \(x) 
     inherits(x, what = c("data.frame", "list")))))))
```

#### Update

Based on the OP's comments, if it is to only everything except `functions`

```
rm(list = names(which(!unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv, 
    \(x) inherits(x, what = "function"))))))
```

Comment: This is very close, but it still leaves two objects (in my case, it leaves a connection object and also a list). I essentially want to remove absolutely everything except for the functions that I have already created.

Comment: I want to remove absolutely everything except for functions.

Comment: Yes, I appear to have made an error in my wording. I will change it.

Comment: I've spotted an error - your answer states that I wish to remove all functions whereas I said I wanted to _keep_ all functions. I modified the `=` to `!=` but that failed. Also, somebody else posted a solution of `rm(list = ls()[sapply(ls(), function(i) class(get(i))) != "function"])` (now deleted for some reason) which works.

Comment: @Mus sorry, that was a mistake.  I updated.  You need the `!` before `unlist`